# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "<URL>"

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Seems like a duplicate? No, it is not!

These are my configurations:

1. OS: Fedora 33 Server
2. PHP: PHP 7.4.13
3. MySQL: MySQL 8.0

I’d set up WordPress on my server like this:

1. Nginx faces the internet.
2. Nginx passes requests to PHP-fpm.
3. PHP-fpm then handle everything after that.

Everything seems to be working fine but I don’t know what the heck is going on? Literally, any kind of theme is not working. I’ve tried so many themes but none of them seems to be working.

Take a look at the page: https://blog.harshrathod.dev

I get this weird warning and the styles to not take effect at all:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "<URL>".
(index):29 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://php.harshrathod.dev/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=5.6".
(index):30 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://php.harshrathod.dev/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=5.6".
(index):31 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://php.harshrathod.dev/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.6".
(index):32 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://php.harshrathod.dev/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/theme.min.css?ver=5.6".
(index):33 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://php.harshrathod.dev/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/style.css?ver=1.8".
(index):34 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://php.harshrathod.dev/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/print.css?ver=1.8".
```

This is my nginx congifguration:

```
root        /usr/share/wordpress;

location / {
    try_files      $uri $uri/ =404;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:4000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: It probably is a duplicate. When a file is not found, you are sending the request to `/index.php` which always responds with `test/html` (this is good because this is how pretty permalinks work). The problem is that these files are not found - either because they are missing, read protected, or Nginx is not configured correctly to locate them.

Comment: Okay, I have provided my nginx configuration. Can you find anything odd here?

Comment: That configuration sends the request to PHP which responds with "access denied" as `text/html`. You should start by changing the `location` to `location ~ \.php$` so that non-PHP files are treated as static files. A complete recipe is [documented here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/).

Comment: Okay, that solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this [issue](https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/2224) I figured out that the actual problem is with my nginx configuration.

Since I only have one and only route, what is happening is that static files are also being parsed by php-fpm and it is sending them to the clients as `html/txt`.

The solution to this is that we need to have two different routes:

1. One for everything static.
2. Second for processing php files.

So, the resulting nginx configuration will look like this:

```
root /usr/share/wordpress;

location / {
    index index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files      $uri $uri/ =404;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:4000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```